# WPF: Keeping an object running?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm having problems understanding how WPF app.xaml works. Is it like Main method in winforms programing?

What I want is a MainController class which keeps track of my Window object. For example:

```
public MainController()
{
  _windowMain = new WindowMain(this);
}

public WindowMain GetWindowMain
{
  get { _windowMain; }
}
```

And so on with all the windows I have in my project. But where should my MainController be initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `StartupUri` property of the `App.xaml` file.  It links in a Window's XAML file within your project to be launched at startup.

If you want to avoid this, then I believe you can override a method in `App.xaml.cs` to launch the window explicitly via your controller.

You should understand that the compiler makes a class called 'App' that overrides [`System.Windows.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx) by compiling your `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` files.  Check the [documentation for that class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx) to learn more about the lifecycle management of your WPF application.